# AutoHotKey Shortcut to Create New File in Windows 8

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Some time back, I found a script online that provides a shortcut to create a new file. It works great for my computer running Windows 7:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
#n:: ;If Windows+N is pressed in Windows Explorer
Send {Alt} ;Menu
Send f ;> File
Send w ;> New
Send t ;select Text Document
Send ^a ;select all
Exit
```

This script won't work for my new laptop running Windows 8. Was just wondering if anyone knows why this is, and if maybe there is a quick edit that can be made to make it work? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the changed menu layout of Win 8 explorer. On my machine, if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> in explorer, you will get overlaying images of buttons next to the corresponding menu which will be updated during menu navigation. You want to get to the Menu `Home` and then choose `New item`. On my machine, that's the key sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>. But a subsequent shortcut to select `text file` (like <kbd>T</kbd>) doesn't seem to exist. On the other hand, AHK can do what you want without relying on the explorer menu, but that requires a bit of coding:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
#n::
    ControlGetText, dir, ToolbarWindow323
    RegExMatch(dir, ":(.*)", dir)
    dir := Trim(dir1)
    FileAppend, , %dir%\MyNewTextFile.txt
return
```

The only downside of this is that it won't work per se for folders you opened via "Favorites" or "Libraries" from explorer. But if you need them, you could still write a workaround for that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works, but like you said, only in certain contexts. Would I need to write workarounds for each individual folders (Desktop, Favorites, etc), or would there be a way to write a single workaround that would make it work for all of those? Also, is there a way to have it end with the file name being editable and all text selected? Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Joe 1) As far as I know, you would have to manually map these folders with their paths, but that's rather trivial and quickly done. 2) Of course,  you can name the file as you desire. 3) What do you mean by "all text selected"?

Comment: By "all text selected," I mean after the shortcut is pressed, instead of the new file being named "MyNewTextFile.txt," the shortcut would end by having all of the text of the file name, whether it's "MyNewTextFile.txt" or "new text document.txt" selected, so I could quickly name the file whatever I need it to be. Essentially the equivalent of if you right click and choose to rename the file. That is how my original shortcut that I posted above worked. Thanks again for all your responses.

Comment: @Joe You could achieve that by popping up an `Inputbox` for example, or maybe blindly typing it using `Input`. A cool but little more complicated way using `Input` would be to update the file name for every keypress. Anyway, it seems that you've found your own solution using the right click menu. Be aware that a) this depends on the mouse position (e.g. while hovering over a file, it won't give you the option to create new files) and b) if the menu takes a longer time to appear (this is especially the case when it was changed before), the subsequent keys may be sent too early.

Comment: Then again, if your solution works for you, we're both happy I guess =)

Comment: I'll experiment with Inputbox too. It actually seems that when I'm using {AppsKey} the way I am, the right click menu pops up in the very top left of the explorer window, independent of where the mouse is. What does matter, is if another file is selected. I do need to make sure no files are selected or it ends up trying to delete said file. And you're right, there could be times where something goes wrong with this, but as long as it works most times, I'm OK with it. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Think I actually came up with something that works in all contexts, Windows 7 and 8:

```
#n::
    Send {AppsKey}
    Send w
    Send t
    Sleep, 400
    Send ^+{Right}
    Send {Del}
return
```

I have to add the Sleep in there because it seems like it's trying to run the proceeding code before the file has time to be created. But this seems to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Windows 10.

Create `NewFile.txt` by `ctrl+shift+M`

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
^+m::
    newFileHere()
    return
#IfWinActive

newFileHere(){
WinHWND := WinActive()
For win in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    If (win.HWND = WinHWND) {
        dir := SubStr(win.LocationURL, 9) ; remove "file:///"
        dir := RegExReplace(dir, "%20", " ")
        Break
    }

file = %dir%/NewFile.txt
if FileExist(file)
{
    MsgBox, NewFile.txt already exists
    return
}
FileAppend,, %file%  ; create new file
}
```